# Can you disable blessings like Daruk's Protection?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Are you able to disable blessings like Daruk's Protection?  I keep wasting it on weaker enemies while I'm on my way to the enemies that I want to actually use it on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can disable any of the blessings by:

1. Opening your "Key Items" menu
2. Select the blessing ("A" on Wii U)
3. Select "Disable"

You can enable the blessing again in the same menu.

[image: Disabling Blessings]

Comment: I never this knew.... this is so useful.